# Can I remove space between leading and actions?

Tags: flutter, dart, widget, cross-platform, appbar

I tried to remove space between leading and actions icon button but I can't, I tried to put all in row but it doesn't work!

```
 appBar: AppBar(
        centerTitle: true,
        title: Text(
          'data',
          textAlign: TextAlign.center,
        ),
        actions: [
          IconButton(icon: Icon(Icons.filter_sharp), onPressed: () {}),
          Directionality(
              textDirection: TextDirection.rtl,
              child: IconButton(
                  icon: Icon(Icons.arrow_back_ios), onPressed: () {})),
        ],
                leading: IconButton(icon: Icon(Icons.search), onPressed: () {}),

        backgroundColor: Theme.of(context).primaryColor,
      ),
```

Comment: what do you mean by removing space?

Comment: I posted a photo that I hope you can see to understand what I meant

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I fixed it by adding alignment to the iconbutton like this:

```
appBar: AppBar(
        centerTitle: true,
        title: Text(
          'data',
          textAlign: TextAlign.center,
        ),
        actions: [
          IconButton(
              icon: Icon(Icons.filter_sharp),
              onPressed: () {},
              alignment: Alignment(5, 0.0)),
          Directionality(
              textDirection: TextDirection.rtl,
              child: IconButton(
                  icon: Icon(Icons.arrow_back_ios), onPressed: () {})),
        ],
        leading: IconButton(icon: Icon(Icons.search), onPressed: () {}),
        backgroundColor: Theme.of(context).primaryColor,
      ),
```

Answer (score 0):

put them into Inkwell widget and the child make it row with to icons.